# Misplaced error dialog in edittext android

Tags: android

I do not have any idea for solving like this:[image]

```
final Drawable d = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_error, getTheme());
d.setBounds(0, 0,
d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
etRegisterFormEmail.setError(getString(R.string.email_not_valid), d);
```

how to fix misplace the error message?

Comment: And we don´t have any idea what the problem is....

Comment: etRegisterFormEmail.setError("Please fill valid form");

Comment: try above code it will work

Comment: @Opiatefuchs message, background and icon are not in right position..

Comment: @Prashantpattar I have tried the coding like that, but i got like the picture..

Comment: @Prashantpattar.. Sorry before.. You are right :), thank you so much..

Comment: it is working...?

Comment: @Prashantpattar, yes it is working :), thanks...

Answer (score 1):

etRegisterFormEmail.setError("Please fill valid form"); – Prashant pattar

+1 +1 +1

Answer (score 0):

I will Give you an Idea.
Use PopupView to display the error dialog and use

```
   popupWindow.showAsDropDown(v);
```

and the popup will be displayed above the View v.